# Remote login via rman working for one instance but not another

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, authentication, remote

I have Oracle 12c installed on two servers.  On server `UAT` I have an instance `RMCAT` that hosts an RMAN recovery catalog.  On server `EXT` I have two instances, `extdev02` and `extuat01`.  I can use the following command on server `UAT` to connect to my `RMCAT` catalog, and target of `extdev02`, but when I try to connect to `extuat01` it gives an `ORA-01017`

```
UAT> rman target= sys/tiger@extdev02  catalog= rmuser/tigerman@rmcat

Recovery Manager: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Wed May 30 22:59:26 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

connected to target database: EXTDEV02 (DBID=4287636681)
connected to recovery catalog database

RMAN> exit


Recovery Manager complete.

UAT> rman target= sys/tiger@extuat01  catalog= rmuser/tigerman@rmcat

Recovery Manager: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Wed May 30 22:59:42 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00554: initialization of internal recovery manager package failed
RMAN-04005: error from target database:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

I get OK results from `tnsping` from `UAT` server to both instances on `EXT`, and I **can** connect to a non-dba user from `UAT` server to both instances.  I recreated the Oracle password file using `orapw` on `EXT` server instance `EXTUAT01` and that did not help.

Instance names are `extdev02` and `extuat01` on server `EXT`.  Here are my password files on that server:

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs> ls -o orapw*
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle 18432 Jun  1 00:07 orapwextuat01
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_0/dbs> ls -o orapw*
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle  7680 Feb  6 20:22 orapwextdev02
```

Note they are in two different ORACLE_HOME directories.  The value for `remote_login_passwordfile` is `EXCLUSIVE` for both instances

### Resolved Problem

The server UAT hosting the RMAN catalog instance `RMCAT` was rebooted a few days ago to add memory, and now I can connect!  If I had a wayback machine, I would go back and see if trying to restart the listener on UAT host would have helped; in any case, it works.   Thanks for the suggestions; I am putting in the answers just for posterity.

### Comments Answered

- Not a Grid nor RAC nor Dataguard instance environment.
- selecting from v$pwfile_users:

extdev02:

```
AtlasExt:SYS@extdev02> select * from v$pwfile_users;

USERNAME  SYSDBA  SYSOPER SYSASM  SYSBACKUP  SYSDG   SYSKM   CON_ID
--------- ------- ------- ------- ---------- ------- ------  ------
SYS       TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE      FALSE   FALSE   0
```

extuat01 (note: I ran orapw specifying sysbackup to no avail)

```
AtlasExt:SYS@extuat01> select * from v$pwfile_users;

USERNAME  SYSDBA  SYSOPER SYSASM  SYSBACKUP  SYSDG  SYSKM    CON_ID
--------- ------- ------- ------- ---------- ------ -------- ------
SYS       TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE      FALSE  FALSE    0
SYSBACKUP FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE       FALSE  FALSE    0
```

- I was **not** able to connect from UAT to EXT instance `extuat01` via SQL*Plus; but after the reboot I was:

extdev02 from UAT:

```
AtlasUAT:SYS@extdev02> select host_name, instance_name from v$instance;

HOST_NAME                 INSTANCE_NAME
------------------------- ----------------
plsekatlasexta01          extdev02
```

extuat01 from UAT:

```
18:25:07 AtlasUAT:SYS@extuat01> select host_name, instance_name from v$instance;

HOST_NAME                 INSTANCE_NAME
------------------------- ----------------
plsekatlasexta01          extuat01
```

- Verified extuat01 and extdev01 processes were running out of the same home:

Found pmon PID:

```
plsekatlasexta01> ps -fu oracle  | grep pmon | grep -v grep
oracle    1976     1  0 Jun01 ?        00:00:43 ora_pmon_extuat01
oracle   32373     1  0 May16 ?        00:02:45 ora_pmon_extdev02
plsekatlasexta01> cat /proc/1976/environ | tr '\000' '\n' | grep -E 'ORACLE_(HOME|SID)'
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1
ORACLE_SID=extuat01
plsekatlasexta01> cat /proc/32373/environ | tr '\000' '\n' | grep -E 'ORACLE_(HOME|SID)'
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_0
ORACLE_SID=extdev02
```

Comment: Is this database (extuat01) registered in Grid Infrastucture? If it is, what is the location of password file in `srvctl config database -db extuat01`? Starting with 12c, databases registered in Grid Infrastructure can have their default password file location overridden with a custom value. Is `sec_case_sensitive_logon` set to `FALSE` (default value is `TRUE`)? That can also cause the above issue.

Comment: No grid infrastructure set up; at least I don't think the previous DBA set one up.  I know `extdev02` is not registered anywhere except in the `tnsnames.ora` on the `UAT` server and its own server.  And that one _is_ working... good idea though.

Comment: `sec_case_sensitive_logon` is set to `TRUE` on all instances.

Comment: Can you verify it using below query on extuat01 instance,
select * from v$pwfile_users;

Comment: 1. Do you have a RAC or dataguard environment? I assume no, is this right.
2. From your description I would conclude that `sqlplus sys/tiger@extdev02 as sysdba` works but `sqlplus sys/tiger@extuat01 as sysdba` gives an ORA-01017 error. Is this right? 
3. connect from UAT with `sqlplus sysem@extuat01` and query instance_name.v$instance and host_name to see if you are connected on the correct instance of the correct host.

Comment: 4. Did you already try the rman connect from the EXT server? I assume you have defined both tns aliases in both tnsnames.ora files on the EXT server. Try out extuat01 from bboth ORACLE_HOMEs. If it does not work for SYS try it out for SYSTEM. 
5. How can you check that the instance is actually started with the environment you claim? Use https://serverfault.com/questions/66363/environment-variables-of-a-running-process-on-unix for the pmon process and check the value of ORACLE_HOME variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server UAT hosting the RMAN catalog instance `RMCAT` was rebooted a few days ago to add memory, and now I can connect to both database instances on EXT server.

I do not remember whether I tried reloading / restarting the TNS listener on the UAT host when it was not working, but now that the server was rebooted it is now working; I assume the reboot got the listener working.  Thanks to all for the helpful comments.